# SharePoint Online - Set all default "document library" to read-only for members and visitors

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is it possible to loop through every site via powershell and set the default document library to all owned sites (including Team sites) to be read-only for everyone but the owners? I've seen and tried a lot of code but I cannot get it to work.

I only want the Team Owner to be able to create documents.

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to achieve that ? Because the main purpose a site owner is to have full-control. Maybe you should consider another approach.

Comment: Fixed the question, I meant to say everyone but owners to read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set-PnPListPermission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistpermission?view=sharepoint-ps) to remove and add users/groups permissions.

If you want to change all libraries of all sites, you need to loop them, then run Set-PnPListPermission to change permissions for each library.

Two blogs for your reference:
[SharePoint Online: Remove User or Group from List Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-remove-user-group-from-list-permissions-using-powershell.html)
[SharePoint Online: Grant Permission to List or Library using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/05/sharepoint-online-grant-permission-to-list-library-using-powershell.html)